# webpack not recognised as command

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-2017, angular5

I am using Visual Studio 2017 for my Angular5 project. I have installed Webpack Task Runner to run the `webpack.config.js`, it does run the task but gives an error

> webpack not recognized as external or internal command

Now I know this is because it doesn't have `webpack` installed but I don't know how to install it. One way is to use `npm task runner` but I don't want to use that, is there any other way to do that in VS2017? I tried installing `webpack` nuget but that doesn't help.

**Note:** My `node_modules` have `webpack` folder but it still shows the error. Also I have `$(PATH)` above `$(DevEnvDir)`

Comment: Find a solution?

Comment: No still searching..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue.

Since I am working on visual machine, I am not allowed to download `node` on that. I downloaded `node` on my local machine and install `webpack` on it but when I copied `node-modules` from it to my visual machine, some of the files were not copied properly to `node_modules/.bin` folder. When I copied `.bin` folder again, it works!